# Convert Epoch to Date in an Long Array

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have pulled data from a API to get an array of dates and values. The dates are all in epoch time such as `1523912075000`. I am trying to make a graph, my issue is I do not know how to change the entire array in standard `MM/DD/YYYY. I tried with this code below but the date did not change at all. Looking for some help.

```
public void onResponse(String response){
  Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("price");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            Long date = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).optLong(0);
                            Long value = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).optLong(1);

                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                            sdf.format(new Date(date));

                            x.add(new Entry(date, value));

                        }
         ...}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format(java.lang.Object)) and see what `format` returns - a `String`

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat::format` returns a `String`, so you can do

```
String dtVal = sdf.format(new Date(date));
x.add(new Entry(dtVal, value));
```

I would also suggest that you move the `SimpleDateFormat` instantiation to before your loop